# What are the faint spoken lines under the playback of Aaron's recording in the second bench scene?

Tags: primer

In the scene in *Primer* where Abe collapses after encountering Aaron at the bench the "second" time, the camera focuses on the swinging earpiece while the soundtrack plays a tinny version of the conversation from the first bench scene. At the same time, very faintly and muffled, the soundtrack seems to have some lines from Abe and/or Aaron -- these presumably would be the lines being spoken by them at that moment in the film even though their faces are off-screen.

This sequence takes place between 1:03:45 and 1:04:20.

Is there any clue what these lines are from the script or any other source? (To clarify: My question is whether anyone knows what are the exact words being said.)

Comment: Can you provide a video link with timestamp?